# Set field visibility dynamically

Tags: fields, visibility, opportunity-teams

We want to assign field visibility on UI level based on whether a user is a member of a specific team or not. E.g. we have an opportunity record and we need to display some fields only if the running user is an opportunity team member.
An approach that comes to mind is to construct a visibility matrix and create a lightning component/visualforce page that will handle this.
Is this possible with standard salesforce functionality?
**Edit** (*after @PhilW's recommendation*):

- We are utilising Lightning experience and dynamic forms.
- The opportunity teams are salesforce's standard ones.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. I don't believe there's enough information here for us to really help you. How "dynamic" are these teams and how are they represented (e.g. relatively static using CRUD/FLS permissions and Sharing or very dynamic using junction objects between opportunities and users)? Are Lightning Experience and Dynamic Forms something you can use or are you using Classic Experience? Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps take the [tour] before you [edit] your question to add more detail.

Comment: @PhilW thank you for the guidelines. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Since your teams are junction objects and you'll have found that visibility rules don't let you use filtered related lists, just master detail and lookup fields, you'll probably have to roll your own solution.

Answer (score -1):

So, you can definitely conditionally hide individual page components on at least the Lightning page layout; doing that looks like this:
[image: Set Component Visibility > Filter By > Advanced]

The other half of that, though, is you'll need a separate component with the field you want to sometimes-hide on it, and to remove the field from the usual "details" section of the Classic page layout.

Well, that, or there's a relatively-new feature called "Dynamic Forms" (that "Upgrade Now" button in the above screenshot) which you can probably use for this. I haven't tried it myself in my production instance, but in the sandbox it looks pretty much exactly like what it sounds like you're looking for.

Comment: Trying to do this with a mix of standard and custom components is bound to result in a poor UX if the form supports not just viewing but also editing - the field would not be editable as part of the record editing.

Comment: This also fails to consider that the condition depends on the contextual user ID being in a junction object record related to the main record. Salesforce does not support visibility conditions using such data, as I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: Okay, apparently I missed the "teams" part of the question (despite it being there since the beginning), and yeah, that specifically causes issues. Can still do it without resorting to Apex, but the flows to tack on multiple user IDs to (a custom field on) the opportunity are an ugly bit of workaround and kind of feel like they're defeating the point of using teams to begin with.